Modify ObjectMapper by Adding New Deserializer
I have a deserialiser:
public class TrimStringDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> implements ContextualDeserializer {

    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<String> createContextual(DeserializationContext ctxt, BeanProperty property) {
        boolean skip = Optional.ofNullable(property)
                .map(prop -> prop.getAnnotation(TrimString.class) == null)
                .orElse(false);
        if (skip) {
            return new StringDeserializer();
        } else {
            return this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        String value = parser.getValueAsString();
        if (value != null) {
            value = value.trim();
        }
        return value;
    }
}

and a config class:
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {
    @Bean
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer() {
        return builder -> builder.modules(modules -> modules.add(new SimpleModule().addDeserializer(String.class, new TrimStringDeserializer())));
    }
}

And an annotation
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE_USE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface TrimString {
}

But the incoming request fields with TrimString annotation are still not trimmed.
If I do that straightforward by adding new module into ObjectMapper, it works.
What am I missing with configuration ?

What is a "TrimString annotation" and why do you believe that it instructs the ObjectMapper to use TrimStringDeserializer to deserialize fields annotated with it?

@lane.maxwell question has been edited
